# Could we add a legal clause in the description box?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Each day there always seems to be two or three questions where the poster should be talking to a lawyer, not an online community.

I think this is always going to be a problem in this kind of format but to help prevent this could we put something in the question box along the lines of:

> The workplace is a community for career and workplace related questions. Legal questions are unable to be answered here.

I would envision this feature working something like the below so as to be noticeable by the user:

[image]

Comment: Note that basic legal questions that require no *interpretation* of the law but rather a simple summary or referral to a specific law *are* on-topic here. Some examples: [explaining exempt versus non-exempt](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/52303/25739) (any HR person in the US should know this), [contracts overriding a legal minimum](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/), [the definition of "hostile workplace"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/54595/25739), applicability of FMLA, whether you can fire a pregnant employee, etc.

Comment: There is also a specific close reason for "questions requiring a lawyer are off topic" too.

Comment: @enderland My suggestion was more to prompt people to write more from a workplace than legal perspective initially. Happy to concede that I have less experience in this community and that this may not work though!